# grep based on regex not matching anything

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, grep

I am trying to `grep` by `regex` but I am having trouble figuring out what is wrong with my regex. I couldnt find any bash regex testers out there so this has been really hard to figure out.

Here is my regex

`[0-9]*\.[0-9]*[G][:space:]*\.\/[bbg-sevent-test-][0-9]*`

I am trying to match my regex to this piece of text

`2.0G    ./bbg-sevent-test-132^M`

The command I am running is:

`./kafka_prefill.sh | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g" | grep '[0-9]*\.[0-9]*[G][:space:]*\.\/[bbg-sevent-test-][0-9]*' > data3.txt`

What this does is run my script, translate/remove parts of my output, then grep based on regex and put it in the file `data3.txt`

I am currently getting this error:

`grep: Invalid range end`

** update ** thanks to Ed Plunkett

updated regex:

`^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*[G][[:space:]]*\.\/bbg-sevent-test-[0-9]*$`

My command no longer has a regex error. However nothing is matching. Here is a sample output:

```
********************************************************************************^M
This is a private computer system containing information that is proprietary^M
and confidential to the owner of the system.  Only individuals or entities^M
authorized by the owner of the system are allowed to access or use the system.^M
Any unauthorized access or use of the system or information is strictly^M
prohibited.^M
^M
All violators will be prosecuted to the fullest extent permitted by law.^M
********************************************************************************^M
Last login: Tue Dec 29 16:43:23 2015 from 10.81.64.204^M^M
sudo bash^M
cd /data/kafka/tmp/kafka-logs/^M
du -kh . | egrep "bbg-sevent-test-*"^M
-bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted^M
### Trinity env = prod ###^M
### Kafka Broker Id = 1 ###^M
### Kafka Broker must be started as root!! ###^M
exit^M
exit^M
### Trinity env = prod ###^M
### Kafka Broker Id = 1 ###^M
### Kafka Broker must be started as root!! ###^M
^[]0;root@ip-10-81-66-20:/home/ec2-user^G^[[?1034h[root@ip-10-81-66-20 ec2-user]# cd /data/kafka/tmp/kafka-logs/^M
^[]0;root@ip-10-81-66-20:/data/kafka/tmp/kafka-logs^G[root@ip-10-81-66-20 kafka-logs]# du -kh . | egrep "bbg-sevent-test-*"^M
2.2G    ./bbg-sevent-test-439^M
2.2G    ./bbg-sevent-test-638^M
2.2G    ./bbg-sevent-test-679^M
2.2G    ./bbg-sevent-test-159^M
```

I am only trying to match this bit

`2.2G    ./bbg-sevent-test-159`

Comment: your `[:space:]` is only matching literal chars `:space`, you need `[[:space:]]`. Also what Ed below indicates. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why is this in square brackets?

```
[bbg-sevent-test-]
```

If you are matching that entire literal string, including brackets, escape them:

```
\[bbg-sevent-test-\]
```

If you're not matching the brackets as literal characters, leave them out:

```
bbg-sevent-test-
```

Looks to me like you don't really want them there. In a regex, text you match literally is just slapped in there as-is, no special syntax required except for escaping special characters like []*+?(). etc.

What you've got there is, syntactically, a range -- but a broken one, since there's nothing after the last hyphen. However, a range is clearly not your intent.

Comment: Thanks for the help! played a little bit with regex and got the answer